# An iso file containing its MD5 hash?

Tags: md5

My colleague remembers and old backup tool, packaged as a standard bootable [ISO image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image). He thinks the file was about ~250 MB, containing a MD5SUM.txt, which included the MD5 Checksum of the entire ISO image.

I am no crypto/hash expert, but according to my understanding of checksum methods, he is wrong. He should have downloaded checksum separately, or else, the vendor should have had a hard time guessing the right MD5 such that adding it's hex form in a text file beside all other contents of the image makes the exact same checksum, right? I can't think of any shortcut to calculate such checksum.

(Unfortunately we don't have the ISO right now, so that I can win the bet and get a free beer.)

Comment: [Not quite on-point, but related Q&A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44463/23623).

Answer (score 2):

With a secure hash function what you are describing is entirely impossible. MD5 is considered totally broken and yet I am unaware of a method of accomplishing this feat even with known multi collision attacks.
SEJPM gave a relevant link to what can be done with multi collision attacks on MD5 but placing the resulting hash in plain text is harder and I don't believe has been done. Definitely didn't happen as a matter of fact implementation detail. Should someone do this even with MD5 it would be a significant cryptography feat.

In order to demonstrate that with a turing complete format it is easy to have a file produce its own hash with no need for cryptanalysis: I created a proof of concept and wrote a Scala program which prints its own SHA-256 hash. This technique can work with any hash function, and any turing complete language, including postscript
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/meirmaor/3d858568d5da35f568fe96687ed7dbaf/raw/c26d3bdd298567e76e92c6c37ab96e353a3d8cdf/QuineHash.scala

> scalac QuineHash.scala
> scala QuineHash
> 6bae798a607d1f74630734435cc93d17c9b92a6705f7663c6fd47f7439c69669
>
> sha256sum QuineHash.scala
> 6bae798a607d1f74630734435cc93d17c9b92a6705f7663c6fd47f7439c69669 QuineHash.scala

Comment: Indeed. However we can make a pdf file that shows the hash of the iso.

Comment: With a Turing complete format like postscript we don't need any cryptography for this. Just calculate your own hash and display it, this will require quine like tricks no cryptanalasis. I'm half tempted to try this with SHA-2/3

Comment: @MeirMaor But... How do you calculate your own hash, when you are made up of your own hash?

Comment: It shoulnd't be harder then a program which prints itself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

Comment: @MeirMaor: I see no way to make a pdf/postscript/executable that displays the sha256 of the iso it was extracted from.

Comment: If we can make a quine we should be able to do the same. When building a quine, we build a string variable with the program source in it, we can have this include a sha256 function. The program will build the string of itself, and call sha256 on it. The SHA256 will not actually appear in source anywhere.

Comment: @fgrieu I edited and added a POC to show code which produces it's own sha256 hash.